# Double integral of log squared

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Reading up on integral equations, the text states as matter of fact that

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1\ln^2|x-y| \, dx \, dy < \infty$$
Wolfram|Alpha confirms that the double integral in fact evaluates to $3.5$, but shows no working, nor any indication of an indefinite solution. Can anyone please give me a pointer on how to tackle this integral?

Comment: Feynman's trick / differentiation under the integral sign is the slickest way to deal with logarithmic integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\alpha>0$ let:
$$ I(\alpha)=\iint_{(0,1)^2}\left|x-y\right|^\alpha\,dx\,dy = 2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)^\alpha\,dy\,dx.\tag{1} $$
We have:
$$ I(\alpha)= 2\iint_{(0,1)^2} x^{\alpha+1}(1-z)^{\alpha}\,dz\,dx =\frac{2}{(\alpha+1)}-\frac{2}{(\alpha+2)}\tag{2}$$
hence:

> $$ \iint_{(0,1)^2}\log^2\left|x-y\right|\,dx\,dy = \left.\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2} I(\alpha)\right|_{\alpha=0^+}=\left.\frac{4}{(\alpha+1)^3}-\frac{4}{(\alpha+2)^3}\right|_{\alpha=0^+}=\color{red}{\frac{7}{2}}.\tag{3} $$

Answer (score 0):

With the substitution $x\leftarrow x+y$ you get $$\begin{eqnarray}2\int_0^1\int_0^x \log^2(x-y)\mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x &=&2\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\log^2(x)\mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x\\ &=& 2\int_0^1 (1-x)\log^2(x) \mathrm{d}x\\ &=& \frac72. \end{eqnarray}$$
The function $(1-x)\log^2(x)$ has a closed form indefinite integral.